# Converting VBScript array to Java Script Array in classic ASP

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP page which is written in VB script, and there is a script tag which Java Script is used as below.

I am trying to cast VB Script Array(codeList) to Java Script Array(availableCode) with for loop but the first row of VB Script Array keeps being casted in every row of Java Script Array.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
var availableCode = new Array();

for (idx=0; idx < 3; idx++) 
{ 
    availableCode[idx]=<%=codeList(idx)%>;
    alert (idx);
    alert (<%=codeList(idx)%>);
    alert (availableCode[idx]);
}
});
```

I tried the below as well but getting a syntax error.

```
availableCode[idx]=<%=codeList(%> idx <%)%>;
```

Could anyone advise how to cast expected values? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it the other way round ie create your index (idx) within VBScript, then write it to the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var availableCode = new Array();
<%
    dim idx
    for idx = 0 to UBound(codeList)
%>  
    availableCode[<%=idx %>] = <%= codeList(idx) %>;
    alert (<%= idx %>);
    alert (<%= codeList(idx) %>);
    alert (availableCode[<%= idx %>]);
<% next %>
});
```

if the elements of codeList are string values, you will need to quote to prevent javascript errors

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    var availableCode = new Array();
<%
    dim idx
    for idx = 0 to UBound(codeList)
%>  
    availableCode[<%=idx %>] = '<%= codeList(idx) %>'; // quote here
    alert (<%=idx %>);
    alert ('<%= codeList(idx) %>'); // quote here
    alert (availableCode[<%= idx %>]);
<% next %>
});
```

The issue you were having I believe was that idx did not exist on the server-side (VBScript) and therefore when used in this statement `<%= codeList(idx) %>`, idx was being converted implicitly to 0. Thus always returning the value in `codeList(0)`.

Comment: Hi oracle certified professional! As the codeList contains string values, I used the 2nd one and now it is working. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Join() to output your array: this will also make your client-side code more compact.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var availableCode = ['<%=Join(codeList, "','")%>'];
```